# SQL how to show all characters before the last '.' after the @ in my database

Tags: mysql, sql, string, substring

(note the database is in Dutch so don't mind the strange names.)

The query I try to create should shows all the characters before and including the last dot ('.') in the emailaddress. But the query I used (but of course doesn't work) shows the data below.

```
SELECT LEFT(mailadres, LENGTH(substring_index(mailadres, '.', 2))+1) AS edited_values, mailadres
FROM reviewers
```

Mailaddresses-values:

- Brechtje.Eefting@hotmail.
- Martijn.Rokx@gmail.
- Rosemijn.Stegers@gmail.
- Ans.Vogelaar@gmail.
- Flip.van.
- Dirck.Boesten@gmail.
- Kobus.van.
- Rikkert.van.
- Lourens.van.

As you can see for some values it does the job, but its not quite what I want.
The values I actually want to see shoud look like this:

- Brechtje.Eefting@hotmail.
- Martijn.Rokx@gmail.
- Rosemijn.Stegers@gmail.
- Ans.Vogelaar@gmail.
- Flip.van.Korsten@gmail.
- Dirck.Boesten@gmail.
- Kobus.van.Dijkstra@gmail.
- Rikkert.van.Hogen@gmail.

How should the query look to get the results above?

Comment: ```SELECT LEFT(mailadres, LENGTH(mailadres) - LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mailadres, '.', -1)))```

Comment: Yup that worked thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want up to the last `.`, you should use a negative count with substring_index:

```
left(mailadres, char_length(mailadres)-char_length(substring_index(mailadres,'.',-1))
```

Note that this substring_index will return the entire string if there is no `.`, resulting in the two lengths being equal and `left` being asked for 0 characters and giving an empty string as a result.  If you want the entire mailadres returned when there is no `.`, you have to explicitly check that:

```
if(instr(mailadres,'.'),left(mailadres, char_length(mailadres)-char_length(substring_index(mailadres,'.',-1))),mailadres)
```

So in full:

```
SELECT
    if(instr(mailadres,'.'),left(mailadres, char_length(mailadres)-char_length(substring_index(mailadres,'.',-1))),mailadres) AS edited_values,
    mailadres
FROM reviewers
```

Comment: Yes it worked, another question does substring_index
'count up to' or 'up to and including' the chosen character or string?

Comment: substring_index returns a string, not a count.  with -1, it will return the substring _after_, not _after and including_, the last `.`.

Comment: I tried {if(instr(mailadres,'.'),left(mailadres, length(mailadres)-length(substring_index(mailadres,'.',-1)),mailadres)}

Note that I am very new to SQL so I don't know how if's work and where to put them in the code so it did not work, could you please explain to me where to put them in my code? I placed the if after the SELECT clause.

Also how can I enclose a piece of code in the comment section?

Comment: I kinda get what you are trying to say with the 'if', I suppose you put the 'if' somewhere in the database itself?

Comment: no, I'm using the if function; you say if(boolean expression,expression for result if true,expression for result if false).   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if

Comment: added a full SELECT statement to my answer

Comment: Another thing I would like to add, is that: left(mailadres, length(mailadres)-length(substring_index(mailadres,'.',-1)) Works for 95% of the values in my database but screws some values up. An example below.

Marike.Çiçek@gmail.co

It should be: Marike.Çiçek@gmail. of course.

Comment: was that originally gmail.co.uk or something?

Comment: Nope, this is the orignal:Marike.Çiçek@gmail.com, so how can I make that query truly waterproof?

Comment: please add `show create table reviewers;` output to your question

Comment: How do I do that, sorry I am very new to programming and SQL as a whole?

Comment: do you have access to the mysql command line client?  where you can type in sql statements and see results?

Comment: that line returned this:
reviewers CREATE TABLE `reviewers` (
   `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `naam` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `mailadres` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=102 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: I was missing a ) in my answer; added it

Comment: in mysql, `utf8` is just a subset of unicode; you almost always want utf8mb4 instead

Comment: ah, in newer versions of mysql/mariadb, you must use char_length, not length.  updating my answer

Comment: Ah yes finally its 100% waterproof but why char_length instead of length? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: in utf8, length in bytes can be greater than length in characters, and left expects characters.  length for that email address was returning 24, char_length is 22.

Comment: Ahh I understand much appreciated for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(email, '^(.*[.])[^.]*$', '$1')
```